# Appcelerator Android keyhash for facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, appcelerator

i am using appcelerator Studio 6.0.4GA SDK , i am having issue by finding `debug.keystore`

when i write in Terminal :

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

its return keyhash , i've put this keyhash in Facebook developer app but its still giving error **key hash not matched** , where i can get this keyhash, since i am using Mac and Appcelerator Studio .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution might help someone else

1- navigate to `/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/<YOUR_SDK_VERSION>`

2- type in terminal

```
keytool -exportcert -alias tidev -keystore dev_keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

3- put the password : `tirocks`

they keyhash will print out

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of key-hashes developers need to put into FB app settings.

**- Development Key Hash -**

As mentioned in [FB docs here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#proguard), you need to run this command for all development builds,

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

- **androiddebugkey** is the key_alias name
- **debug.keystore** is the keystore file name which is stored in your mac user home-directory in a hidden folder **.android**
- after running this command, it will ask for a password, put **android**, it's the default password for this default keystore.

**- Production Key Hash -**

Same command is used to get production key-hash but with your own keystore file, alias_name & password.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <alias_name> -keystore <keystore_file_path> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

- put **alias_name** as same as you used to create your production keystore.
- put same password you used to generate your production keystore.

Comment: i did so , its still not work , `debug.keystore` is not exists in my mac where i can find this file ?

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of your mac's user's directory?

Answer (score 0):

To save the work, you can simply use `zON/CPoDnIgHvMure4hh9HWdR58=` which represents the default dev-keystore for Titanium Android apps.